# how to migrate data in django with sqlite3

Tags: python, django, django-models, sqlite, django-migrations

I keep getting this error after following the official steps on the django web page:

> return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
>
> django.db.utils.OperationalError: database is locked

My issue is that i am trying to migrate data from old column to a new column:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models, migrations

def move_names(apps, schema_editor):
    Comment = apps.get_model("article", "Comment")
    for comment in Comment.objects.all():
        try:
            comment.first_name, comment.second_name = comment.name.split(" ")
        except:
            comment.first_name, comment.second_name = comment.name, ""
        comment.save()

def backwards(apps, schema_editor):
    for comment in Comment.objects.all():
        comment.name = ""
        comment.save()

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('article', '0007_auto_20141109_2005'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(move_names),
        #migrations.RunPython(backwards),
    ]
```

Comment: Are you accessing the sqlite database from another script? Make sure you don't have the development server or a dbshell session open when attempting the migration.

Comment: There is a note about that problem in the documentation (workaround by increasing timeout): https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/databases/#database-is-locked-errors